# Why is view not schema bound even though schema binding is specified?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create the following Indexed View from a view called "Executionlog3" in ReportServer Database.
I have read and think im following all [requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) to create this indexed view, which are mainly that:

- Must specify 2-part names, e.g. schema.entity_name
- Indexed View must be created in the same database as referenced entity
- `WITH SCHEMABINDING` should be specified
- using any join except outer join

However I am getting the following error:

> Cannot schema bind view 'dbo.USAGE_INFO'. 'dbo.ExecutionLog3' is not schema bound.

Is it because [Executionlog3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/report-server-executionlog-and-the-executionlog3-view?view=sql-server-ver15) is a view and an indexed view can only be created using TABLES as the referenced entities?

Here is my view query:

```
--Set the options to support indexed views.

SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF;
SET ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, ARITHABORT,
   QUOTED_IDENTIFIER, ANSI_NULLS ON;
GO

--Create view with schemabinding.

CREATE VIEW dbo.[USAGE_INFO]
   WITH SCHEMABINDING
   AS  
    SELECT  [InstanceName]
            ,[ItemPath]
            ,ca.name as ObjectName
            ,(case
                when ca.type = 1 then 'Folder'
                        when ca.type = 2 then 'Report'
                        when ca.type = 3 then 'Resources'
                        when ca.type = 4 then 'Linked Report'
                        when ca.type = 5 then 'Data Source'
                        when ca.type = 6 then 'Report Model'
                        when ca.type = 7 then ' Report Part (SQL 2008 R2, unverified)'
                        when ca.type = 8 then 'Shared Dataset (SQL 2008 R2)'
                        when ca.type = 13 then 'PowerBI Report'
                        End ) as ObjectType
                                
            ,[UserName]
            ,[ExecutionId]
            ,[RequestType]
            ,[Format]
            ,[Parameters]
            ,[ItemAction]
            ,[TimeStart]
            ,[TimeEnd]
            ,[TimeDataRetrieval]
            ,[TimeProcessing]
            ,[TimeRendering]
            ,[Source]
            ,[Status]
            ,[ByteCount]
            ,[RowCount]
            ,[AdditionalInfo]
        FROM dbo.[ExecutionLog3] e
        join Catalog ca
        on ca.Path = e.ItemPath where ItemAction = 'ConceptualSchema' or ItemAction = 'QueryData'
GO
```

Comment: The error message is telling you the problem, `'dbo.ExecutionLog3' is not schema bound.` Schema bound views can only include views that are schema bound themselves.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning but ExecutionLog3 is in dbo schema...

Comment: That doesn't make it schema bound. `CREATE VIEW .. WITH SCHEMABINDING` is what makes it a schema bound view, preventing underlying views and tables from being changed.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning but how come this example here https://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2011/2/6/querying-the-report-server-execution-log.html has a select from dbo.Executionlog3? that tells me that Executionlog3 View is bound to dbo schema...

Comment: @AlwaysLearning would this be the right syntax? `WITH SCHEMABINDING FROM dbo.[ExecutionLog3] e`

Comment: No, that's incorrect syntax. You would need to use `CREATE VIEW dbo.ExecutionLog3 WITH SCHEMABINDING AS...` to recreate that view with schema binding. This is a Microsoft-supplied view in the ReportServer database - you would have to weigh up the risks and benefits of doing that yourself. One risk is that you could break future Cumulative Updates and Service Packs for SQL Server if they try to modify any of the tables that dbo.ExecutionLog3 depends upon. I would look for alternatives. Why do you need an indexed view?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Our Hyperingestion team said that they cannot ingest data in hue from a ExecutionLog3 because its a view, it has to be a table or materialized view. since then, ive been researching about materialized view, and it turns out thats just indexed view in SQL terms. so thats why im trying to query Executionlog3 into an indexed view. If this is not feasible then its fine, i can just write a script that inserts into a table from the ExecutioLog3 view on a daily basis...i was just hoping to avoid that if indexed view was going to work.

Comment: @Cataster That last comment should have been included in your description of the problem. Perhaps your "team" is incorrect and just does not know how to use a view within that tool (which you should tag)? Something seems terribly wrong when a tool that uses a database as a source of data cannot use a view as easily as a table.

Comment: @SMor I used to include detailed info like that in past posts but i would end up with votes to close the post due to ambiguity (irrelevance to the question) so thats why i avoided including that detail here.  but to your point, youre right, i found it very odd that the only source they can ingest from is tables. i offered them csv files as source and they said they cant injest from that either...apparently they built the functionality to ingest from views in nonprod environment but they still dont have it and dont plan to have it in prod anytime soon, but execs need this usage info right away